# How to get default wordpress admin styles

Tags: css, wordpress, admin

I'm trying to find default wordpress styles for default color schema.

I'm able to find css styles for all other color schemas like (light, blue, coffee etc.) but I'm not able to find the file with the "default" color scheme.

Does anyone know where is it located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These admin styles are actually [dynamically built](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/57c2b5d1921420f860c9e75bfb44c66fe8e3f986/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L661) from files in the [`/wp-includes/css/`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/57c2b5d1921420f860c9e75bfb44c66fe8e3f986/wp-includes/css) and [`/wp-admin/css/`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/57c2b5d1921420f860c9e75bfb44c66fe8e3f986/wp-admin/css) directories.

However, if you need to add or modify styles, you should consider [enqueueing a custom stylesheet](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes), instead of touching the core CSS files.

Comment: was afraid that this would be true. Now I'm afraid.

thx for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer actually is no, there is not a compiled list of css styles for wordpress(admin). at least that I can find...